# Find files ending with *.html but not *-partial.html

Tags: linux, shell, gruntjs, find

I'm refactoring some build tasks in my grunt and I'm trying to find a way to search for files ending with `.html` but not `-partial.html`

Is there some tool or commandline to find all these files?

Not working example:
`find *.html --exclude=*-partial.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` supports logical operators, specifically `-and` and `-not`, so you could look for all the files that end in `.html` but do not end in `-partial.html`:

```
find . -name "*.html" -and -not -name "*-partial.html"
```